# How to insert post tags inside Amazon affiliates script in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This is the Amazon affiliate script. I want to insert the article tags inside the following line:

```
amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "ARTICLE TAGS";
```

This is the whole script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "XXXXXXX";
amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "bottom";
amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
amzn_assoc_region = "US";
amzn_assoc_title = "We recommend these products";
amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "ARTICLE TAGS";
amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
amzn_assoc_linkid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
</script>
<script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
```

I haven't been able to figure out what to do. Nothing I tried works for me.